# Load custom grammar file using GATE developer

Tags: gate

I am new to GATE (General Architecture for Text Engineering). Can anyone tell me how to load a custom grammar file and add it to application.

Comment: thanks for the response, I was able to solve it using Ian's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Load the ANNIE plugin if it isn't already loaded
- Right-click (ctrl-click on mac) Processing Resources in the tree
- new -> JAPE Transducer
- set the grammarURL parameter to point to your jape file

You can add the new PR to your application by moving it from the left hand list to the right hand one in the application editor (double-click the application in the tree) and use the up/down buttons to move it to the right place in the pipeline.